# how do I refer to bathrooms that are completely full / unavailable?

Tags: word-choice

I wanted to say something like "No matter where I go the bathrooms are always all full. Do I use any of these:"満席?いっぱい?全使用中？空いていない？

In which case saying the bathroom is "full" is one way to say it, but how would I also say it conversely with the bathrooms are unavailable (because they are full)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say...

あそこのトイレ、いっつも**いっぱい**で[入]{はい}れない。
昼休みはトイレ**混んで**て入れない。
トイレ(の個室)、**全部使用中**。
女子トイレ、一つも**空いてない**。
女子トイレが**[満室]{まんしつ}**だったから、男子トイレに入った。